# jquery. something wrong with syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#buttons1').on('click', function(event) {             

    $('#button1content').toggle('show');
    var wasVisible = $("#button1content").is(":visible");
    if(!wasVisible) {
        $("#buttons1").css("opacity", "0.5");
    }
});
```

Toggle works perfectly fine, but whatever is inside the if statement doesn't get executed when `#button1content` is no longer visible. boo. It could be another part of my code that is messing it up, but I only want to know if there is anything wrong with this.

Comment: can you provide plunkr or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Typo? Did you mean to pass `'slow'` vs. `'show'`? If that's not meant to be a `duration`, [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be called without arguments to change whether the element is showing or hiding.

Comment: thanks for helping everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `wasVisible` will always return a `true`

- you can place the `toggle` on the last part.

you can reorder your code like this.

```
$('#buttons1').on('click', function(event) {             

    var wasVisible = $("#button1content").is(":visible");
    if(!wasVisible) {
        $("#buttons1").css("opacity", "0.5");
    }
    $('#button1content').toggle('show'); 
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6g5fg97t/7/)**

---

OR

---

- just simply remove the `'show'` on the `toggle` just use

  `$('#button1content').toggle();`

like this:

```
$('#buttons1').on('click', function(event) {             

    $('#button1content').toggle();
    var wasVisible = $("#button1content").is(":visible");
    if(!wasVisible) {
        $("#buttons1").css("opacity", "0.5");
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1psuqjsu/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is not reachable because you always showed `button1content`

```
 $('#button1content').toggle('show');
```

So `var wasVisible = $("#button1content").is(":visible");` will always result to true

Comment: if statement doesn't get executed when #button1content is no longer visible ?

Comment: how toggle always show ?? what's the purpose of using toggle ?

Comment: everytime button is clicked, button1content is always visible,

Comment: then? tell me whats your opinion

Comment: @Euphoria, you did spot the problem but your answer could be modified to say that, the if statement always results to be falsey because `wasVisible` is always true. If statement is not reachable is misleading :)

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary sorry not that good at english :) you can edit my answer bdway

Comment: I have edited but I doubt if it will be accepted as it would be changing the original intention by you, who answered.. Lets see :)